# Query tags from InfluxDB with respect of timeFilter for Grafana variables templating

Tags: grafana, influxdb

We use InfluxDB tags as variables in Grafana and we would like to limit tags by time range selected there.

Using $timeFrame is supported for select InfluxDB queries but tags are returned by "SHOW TAGS" which doesn't support $timeFrame: 
https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/5668

Select can return tags only in case you return value as well and as a result, you have an array which is not supported in Grafana: 
[image]

Does anyone know any workaround how to get tags based on time range?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Found workaround using select, subquery and distinct:

```
select DISTINCT("name") from (select "name","value" from "http_req_duration" WHERE $timeFilter AND  "group" =~ /^$Group$/ AND "TestName" =~ /^$TestName$/)
```

I'm sure will be useful for others.

Comment: Correct answer.  Have also observed that you need to select 'Refresh' == 'Time Range Change' for this to work.